# Stagger animation run when component is in the screen view

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have an Angular animation to display a list of elements:

```
export const list = trigger('list', [
    transition(':enter', [
        query('@listItem', stagger(250, animateChild()))
    ]),
  ]);
```

then the other animation:

```
export const listItem =
    trigger('listItem', [
        transition(':enter', [
            style({ transform: 'scale(.9)', opacity: 0 }),
            animate('1s cubic-bezier(.8, -0.6, 0.2, 1.5)',
                style({ transform: 'scale(1)', opacity: 1 }))
        ])
    ]);
```

I have my html:

```
<div @list class="row justify-content-center">
   <div @listItem class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 mb-3">
      a
   </div>
   <div @listItem class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 mb-3">
      b
   </div>
   <div @listItem class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 mb-3">
      c
   </div>
</div>
```

All that works fine and the animation is behaving as expected. What I want to do is to trigger that animation when the component is visible in the screen. I then did something like:

```
<div [@list]="state" class="row justify-content-center">
       <div @listItem class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 mb-3">
          a
       </div>
       <div @listItem class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 mb-3">
          b
       </div>
       <div @listItem class="col-sm-10 col-md-4 mb-3">
          c
       </div>
    </div>
```

and set in the animation:

```
export const list = trigger('list', [
    transition(':enter, hide => show', [
        query('@listItem', stagger(250, animateChild()))
    ]),
  ]);
```

In the component itself I have the following code:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    public state: string;

    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef,
                @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.updateState();
    }

    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    checkScroll() {
        this.updateState();
    }

    private updateState = (): void => {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            const componentPosition = this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetTop;
            const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
            if (scrollPosition >= componentPosition) {
                this.state = 'show';
            } else {
                this.state = 'hide';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work. I've been looking at different examples and they didn't work. I bet this is a very simple syntax change but I can't get this right. Any help is much appreciated.